# How to print only changed dirs in SVN using Groovy?

Tags: svn, groovy

I am able to print Changeset or changed files from SVN using Groovy

```
List<LogEntry> items = changeSet.getItems()

def affectedFiles = items.collect { it.paths }

fileNames.each { out.println  it.path  }
```

Likewise, I want to get the list of 'dirs-changed' from SVN using Groovy.

In other words I want the functionality of 'svnlook dirs-changed' using Groovy.  Any help or sample URL is highly appreciated

Comment: what library are you using to communicate svn server? any problem in your code? what is the desired result?

Comment: The code snippet I pasted above is for 'getting list of changed files'.  Likewise, I want the 'groovy' code for 'svnlook dirs-changed'